# Keep <li> in line around picture

Tags: css, html-lists

I have an image on the left, and I have a couple paragraphs and a `<ul>` with several `<li>` down the right side. My `<li>` is wrapping around the image. How do I make the `<li>`'s consistent past the image.

Here's an image to clarify what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Nice drawing... Where's the code?

Answer (score 0):

if your code is somehow alike `<img style="float">  <ul>`:
Then you have a few ways to stay aside that floatting element :)

```css
img, #floatleft {float:left;}
#displaytable {display:table;}
#overflowhidden {overflow:hidden;}
#displayinlineblock {display:inline-block;}
ul:before {content:'My id is:'attr(id)' . Do i behave allright ?';color:red;display:list-item;}
```

```html
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="i float"/>
    <ul id="overflowhidden">
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
    </ul>
<hr/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="i float"/>
    <ul id="displaytable">
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
    </ul>
<hr/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="i float"/>
<ul id="displayinlineblock">
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
    </ul>
<hr/>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50" alt="i float"/>
    <ul id="floatleft">    
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
      <li> li lorem blablaum</li>
    </ul>
```

You can take a look at : http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html to start find out about  ways of dealing with float

Comment: Brrr, never liked the abuse of `overflow:hidden`. That's not what it's meant for. Why not simply float the ul left as well?

Comment: @BramVanroy what ever, but then you have to clear the floatting <ul> too at some point :) . to me it is the simpliest way, but you have display:table too that will hold inside floatting elements and will stand aside from outside floatting element as much as overflow does ;)

Comment: As with many things in coding, not the simplest things are the best ones. Building a design with tables might be easier, but not better. Clearing an element with overflow hidden is the same. The best way to clear an element (or multiple floated ones) is (imo) [this trick](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/). `.group:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}`

Comment: @BramVanroy ?? my examples shows an image aside an ul ? it has nothing to do with wrapping a floatting element, just not to go under it wich is a very basic , common confusing situation for a beginner. what about <table> ?

Comment: I never said it should be inside. Overflow hidden is simply a dirty hack that happens to work but that's not the best way to clear elements. When I mentioned that, you waved me off with 'whatever' and I'm disappointed that someone with your rep doesn't take feedback from other users. Don't use overflow:hidden, we are not living in 2009 anymore. And that's all I have to say anymore.

Comment: @BramVanroy okay, to me it is not a hack , it is a specifity and it is not dirty, it is one way, and **no** , there is no better ways, theres is opportunities and choices to make. Lets try to set both img and ul as :in a)inline-block or b)inline-table, or c)table-cell, or even use display:flex on wrapper of them both. there is hundreds of ways to put 2 tags aside each others ;), then you have to deal with your choice if it was or not the best at first ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the text around the image using the float function such as

```
#PictureId {Float: left;}.
```

Using a float function would align all of the li tags at the same spot to the right of the picture.  This spot can be edited by adjusting the padding-right on the image.
Float functions are further explained at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp or at http://www.littlewebhut.com/css/float/.
I would give more specific CSS commands but I the image is appearing as a 1 x 1 blank pixel on my screen.

Comment: hello, what i understand from its drawings, he just looks for the opposite : <ul> going straight down and **not** lay beneath the image with <li> wrapping under it  ;)

Comment: The float command would achieve that effect.  The picture would float left and would eliminate any padding and wrapping of the <li> on the right side.  Further reading on how to best implement float functions are at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_float.asp and at http://www.littlewebhut.com/css/float/.